# SQL: Select a column where a longer string is like a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, where-clause, sql-like

I want to change some data in the database where the text of a column is in a string.

For example we have the String: 'QWZ-$ §_REMARKIUFZQ'

Now I want to select a column where the column name has the text 'Mark'.

Something like this stupid try:

```
SELECT info FROM database WHERE '%'+name+'%' LIKE 'QWZ-$ §_REMARKIUFZQ'
```

Best Regards,

Christian

Comment: tag your database

Comment: You mean you want that I upload the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

> The operand to the right of the LIKE operator contains the pattern and the left hand operand contains the string to match against the pattern.

Switch the LIKE operands i.e. `WHERE 'QWZ-$ §_REMARKIUFZQ' LIKE '%'||name||'%'` (notice `+` changed to sqlite concatenate operator `||` for native sqlite syntax).

Assuming sqlite3 version >= 3.16, you may find the table valued function [`pragma_table_info`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) is the place to look.

Comment: Yeah I tried it first changed but used the + ... damn thank you